# Session not getting destroyed on logout?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I`m working on a codeigniter website which is integrated with a core php website. The problem is when i logout session are not getting destroyed or unset, if user click back button, he/she can go back to internal pages, also it will not allow other user to login, because a session is already running.

I already tried unsetting and destroying session using corephp but no luck, please suggest something.

this is my logout code

```
        function logout()
    {
    session_start();

    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_name','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('business_id','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('email','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_type','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('activation_status','');
    unset($_SESSION); 
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
      session_destroy();
    header('location:'.base_url().'Login');


     }
```

edit: it works on private browser but not on normal one

Comment: before `unset($_SESSION)` try to print the `$this->session`. what does it displays?

Comment: i don't know what is the exact function destroying session in codeigniter but i think this much is ok:- `function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    session_destroy();
    header('location:'.base_url().'Login');
  }`

Comment: You only need `$this->session->sess_destroy();` comment out all the rest and see if it works, don't need the `session_start()` either.

Comment: initially it was only $this->session->sess_destroy(); but it is integrated with a core php site,which is the main site, thats why i`m applying session_destroy(); but it still not working

Comment: What is your configuration in application/config/config.php  $config['sess_use_database']

Comment: hello vipin it is set at "true"

Answer (score 2):

```
Try something like this

$data = array(
'user_id' => '',
'user_name' => '',
'business_id' => '',
'email' => '',
'user_type' => '',
'activation_status' => '',    
);

$this->session->set_userdata('my_session',$data);

To Destroy Session

$this->session->sess_destroy('my_session');
```

Comment: please explain how is it any different from what i was doing above?

Answer (score 0):

Using the codeigniter session library it should be as simple as

```
function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('/');
}
```

Make sure you have the session library loaded in this controller (or autoloaded)

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Also instead of setting blank userdata in your session, you could unset individual items in your session like this

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $array = ('user_id', 'user_name', 'business_id', 'email', 'user_type', 'activation_status');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($array);
```

Comment: tried that not working, the sesson we are getting are also from main core php site, thats why i applied that but not working

Comment: you need to print $this->session object and check that. there might be possibility that you are creating another session on the redirect page.

Comment: it gives a notice Undefined variable: _SESSION, but if i go on previous page, data will still show in session

Comment: As you commented above you are also using core php site? In that case you need to check first session then destroy that session.

Comment: i`m destroying core php session but not helping.

Comment: @AishwaryTiwari then you need to destroy session cookie as given in the example in the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). This is only way that i am thinking